# Why does alien need sudo privilege?

Tags: sudo, alien

I wonder why does [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) need `sudo` privileges while converting a **.rpm** file to **.deb** in a non-privileged directory(eg. my home directory).

Is this a security feature(which I believe is redundant, since installing the package would need dpkg, which needs sudo privileges)?

Comment: Probably just an oversight as in general you should not need to run as root to convert. With that said, IMO alien should be used only as a last resort. Build from source if at all possible. rpm do not always easily convert to .deb due to naming of libraries, installation scripts, dependency checking, etc.

Comment: Please mention the reason before flagging to be closed.

Comment: You should probably file a bug report against alien as yours is not really a technical question.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I need to know if this *is* a bug and not a misunderstanding.

Comment: More a feature request, but bug reports are how you file such things.

Comment: Close voters: This is a good question with a good answer, there is no need to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because packages can contain files owned by different users and I believe the conversion process extracts the files and then builds a .deb from there.  Setting the permissions on the extracted files requires root access.

Note that you should be able to use `fakeroot` to work around this.

Comment: `Because packages can contain files owned by different users` - which files, for example?

Comment: @Jobin, all of them?  Most files are owned by root, some are owned by other system accounts.  None of them are going to be owned by your uid.